# Compiling a C# program in MonoDevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

I know this is a very silly and easy problem, but I can't figure it out by myself.

I wrote my first program in C#. In order to debug it, I've been using an online compiler, but I ran out of free runs, and I know that I need to learn to use MonoDevelop soon anyways.

It looks like a perfect environment for writing and running C# programs even on a mac, but I still can't add a program to a solution of a project, so I can't get it compiled.

Any advice will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A project compiles a set of source files to a library or an executable. A solution is a container for one or more projects. If you create a new project, a solution will be created automatically. Did you try creating and running the default console app project?

Comment: Sounds like you've created a C++ project, instead of C#.

Comment: Thanks mhutch! At least I somehow understood the basic notions. My current problem is that I keep getting the error message "Compiler not found: gcc". A gcc compiler seems to be installed though; do you have any idea what could help? –

Comment: I'm confused - are you trying to create a C# or C project?

Comment: Ah, yes, that's true, the project is only on c++ level. Still, if I run it as a .cs or .css file, I get the same error message. Do you know what is the role of gcc in this process?

Comment: gcc is the C and C++ compiler. You would only have that error if you created a C or C++ project. Try recreating the project and make sure it's a C# project.

Comment: I admit I don't understand what qualifies it as a C++ project. It was written in C# and saved as .cs. If I enter the program here, could you tell me what makes MonoDevelop think it's C++?

Comment: Well, it's too long to be pasted in here, but it really was written in c#, and other compilers recognize it as c#. Maybe it could help if I move some of the gcc folders somewhere else? I really appreciate help.

Comment: I installed Xamarin and everything works well. Thank you for your help!